# How to execute two different Vuex actions sequentially from a component method with async/await

Tags: async-await, nuxt.js, vuex

I am saving user data first in Vuex store, and then in database through API call.

```
export const actions = {
  async userStateUpdate({ commit }, payload) {
    await commit('USER_UPDATE', payload)
  },
  async userDatabaseUpdate({ state }) {
    await this.$axios.post('api/user', {
      user: state.user,
    })
  }
}
```

I'm calling these two methods this way in my component:

```
methods: {
  async update(path, value) {
    await this.$store.dispatch('userStateUpdate', { path, value })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('user saved in state')
        this.$store.dispatch('userDatabaseUpdate')
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log('user saved in database')
      })
      .catch(err) => {
        console.log('user not  saved in store?? or database??')
        console.log(err)
      })
  }
}
```

Is it a recommended way of using `async`/`await` ?
How to know in the last `catch` if the error comes from the first or from the second action ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could use just `async/await` syntax and separate out the error checking with `try/catch`:

```js
async update(path, value) {
  // Update Vuex
  try {
    await this.$store.dispatch('userStateUpdate', { path, value });
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('error updating store');
    // return;   // You could exit here to avoid a database update on error
  }
  // Update database
  try {
    await this.$store.dispatch('userDatabaseUpdate')
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('error updating database');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would say that it would make more sense to have one action here unless there are specific requirements not to. No real need to save the intermediate user state before making the request. You can either update the user in the store based on the response from the POST or merge your updated user into store in the USER_UPDATE mutation.

```
export const actions = {
  async userDatabaseUpdate({ state }, { user }) {
    const response = await this.$axios.post('api/user', { user })
        .catch(err) => {})
    
    try {
        commit('USER_UPDATE', response)
    } catch(err) {

    }
  }
}
```

or

```
export const actions = {
  async userDatabaseUpdate({ state }, { user }) {
    try {
        commit('USER_UPDATE', user)
    } catch(err) {

    }

    const response = await this.$axios.post('api/user', { user })
        .catch(err) => {})
  }
}
```